# Launch YouTube App by pushing play button in an embedded YouTube clip in webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube, youtube-api

I'm looking for a solution about YouTube in Android.

When my WebView in app connects an webpage, some pages may have embedded YouTube clip.

When I press the RED play button in the center of embedded clip, it plays well. Yes I set enabled JavaScript , plugins, hardware acceleration etc. But it ONLY plays in the WebView internal media player.

I've tried with several libraries such like YouTube API that provided by Google, but It just provides Views and interfaces, and cannot convert a YouTube clip in WebView to a YouTubeView (If you know how to convert, let me know).

All I want is simple. Hit a red play button in embedded YouTube, then my app launches YouTube App (or stock media player) so play the YouTube clip.

iPhone can do this very simply with the stock player, but I can't understand why Android can't do so.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether "YouTube" application is install on your device? If yes then just update it.And most of the time you tube application not working properly on emulator..